# Issue with jquery selectors within group & looping over elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

My issue is 2 fold. I have the following code:

```
$photosContainer = $("#photos-fs")
$photos = $photosContainer.find(".photo");
$length = $photos.length;

if ($length > 1) {
    setTimeout(showNextPhoto, 3000);
}

function showNextPhoto() {

    //$current = $photos.eq(0); <-- this works
    //$next = $photos.eq(1); <-- this works

    $current = $photos.find(".current"); <-- this does not
    $next = $current.next(); <-- this does not

    //do stuff with the selected elements here
}
```

What i am trying to achieve is essentially find the .current classed element within a container and its next sibling (or first of the group, if the current is last), then animate them by adding css classes. The problem is that while i can get the elements fine with .eq(0) and .eq(1), they will not be selected "right" when using the class (.current) or the next() function. If i console log the objects i get proper objects though?

I have always used the find(".blahblah") way to navigate myself between classed elements within a group, so not sure why its not working here? Might be something dumb though?

For reference, this is the html structure:

```
<div id="photos-fs">
    <div class="photo current" style="background-image: url(images/fs-image-01.jpg);"></div>
    <div class="photo" style="background-image: url(images/fs-image-02.jpg);"></div>
</div>
```

Also, is there a nice looking and elegant way to test for the last item, so if the current item is last (perhaps with .last?) could you please share that with me as well?

cheers!

Comment: your ".current" is supposed to switch from picture to picture isn't it? ".current" is applied only on the visible one, right?

Comment: is it solved with .filter or not? .find should work too... http://api.jquery.com/find/

Comment: I know mate, i have been using find all my life, but i guess when caching elements, filter is the key.. if you are selecting live all the time, find should work fine? Filter worked fine, only waiting for a few minutes to select the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) instead of [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) in statement.

*Use*

```
$photos.filter(".current");
```

*instead of*

```
$photos.find(".current");
```

*to test for the last item, so if the current item is last*

You can use [.is()](http://api.jquery.com/is/)

```
yourElement.is(':last')
```

Comment: Fantastic, worked fine... how could i ever forget filter?? dumb me! Many thanks!